# Link filecontentresult from a razor view? Only getting the text dump via action/url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, icalendar, actionresult

Using the ical.net nuget package, I wanted to put together a simple ical download link for events that show up in a custom list.

I've tried using an actionlink, and Html.Beginform in the view, but both give the same result. Just a 404, with the url/controller/action?start="ical text contents". Is there a different way I need to be calling this to get an actual file name?

```
[HttpPost]
    public FileContentResult DownloadiCal(DateTime start, DateTime end, string name, string location, string description)
    {
        var e = new CalendarEvent
        {
            Start = new CalDateTime(start),
            End = new CalDateTime(end),
            Location = location,
            Description = description
        };

        var calendar = new Calendar();
        calendar.Events.Add(e);

        var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
        var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);

        byte[] calendarBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);  //iCal is the calendar string

        return File(calendarBytes, "text/calendar", "event.ics");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learned how to chill and realized that there's an issue with routing. Resolved that and I'm #blessed with ics files and Stackoverflow knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working using a web api controller.

```
using System;
using Ical.Net;
using Ical.Net.CalendarComponents;
using Ical.Net.DataTypes;
using Ical.Net.Serialization;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace DEMO.API
{
    public class CalendarsController : ApiController
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/calendar")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            IHttpActionResult response;
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            var e = new CalendarEvent
            {
                Start = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now),
                End = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)),
                Location = "Eric's Cube",
                Description = "Chillin at Eric's cube. who you with? me and my peeps why you bring 4 of your friiiiiieeeends."
            };

            var calendar = new Calendar();
            calendar.Events.Add(e);

            var serializer = new CalendarSerializer();
            var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);

            byte[] calendarBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);  //iCal is the calendar string

            responseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(calendarBytes);
            responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/calendar");
            response = ResponseMessage(responseMessage);

            return response;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to look at how I'm chillin. Also, I'll try and use this as a base for merging into my page controller. Thanks

Comment: base class'n gotsta burn em.